# What is known about the analytic continuation of Maz'ya's modified harmonic zeta function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-zH_n}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, analytic-continuation

### Question:

If we let $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$  be the harmonic numbers then we can consider the modified zeta function

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-zH_n } = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-z(\ln(n)+\gamma +...)} $$

I'm curious what is known about the analytic continuation of this function to all of $\mathbb{C}$?

### Context:

Compare this with

$$ \zeta(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-z\ln(n)} $$

I was made aware of this function by page 36 problem 72 of the article "[Seventy Five (Thousand) Unsolved Problems in Analysis and Partial Differential Equations](https://users.mai.liu.se/vlama82/pdf/Problems2018l_0312.pdf)" by Vladimir Maz’ya.

Maz'ya states the analytic continuation of the fundamental solution (lets call it $U$) to

$$ \left( \frac{d}{dx} + A\right)[U] =  \delta(x)$$

Is an open problem. Here $A$ is the operator given by a line integral over the complex unit circle $C$ and $y$ is some parametrization of the unit circle from $t_0, t_1$: (Credit to @[Kakashi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801814/understanding-vladimir-mazyas-problem-72-what-is-dy) for clarifying the notation)

$$ A[G](x)  = \int_{\text{C}} \frac{G(x)-G(y)}{|x-y|}|dy| = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \frac{G(x)-G(y(t))}{|x-y(t)|}|y'(t)| dt$$

Maz'ya states that this $U$ function is reminiscent of the "modified zeta function" at the start of this question. I personally haven't seen any literature on scholar.google nor has approach-0 yielded any hits for the modified zeta function so I wanted to ask about it. Do we have a formula for its analytic continuation? Are there are any known functional equations, identities, special values etc...